# Development of portlets - Websphere portal

Tags: websphere-portal

In the code of the portlet project for IBM Websphere Portal
How can I validate if the portlet maked  with JSR 168 o JSR 286?
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look in the portlet.xml it will have the spec defined
otherwise JSR 286 just added to the spec so it will have additional methods that 168 did not